# 'Implicit' Garbage Collection doesn't reduce memory footprint. GC.Collect() does

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have application that is processing large amount of data and I'm monitoring .NET memory performance counters for it.
Based on perf counters the #Bytes in All Heaps is slowly growing (about 20MB per 12 hours).
All 3 generations are also being collected (gen0 few times per second, gen1 approximately once per second, gen2 approximately once per minute) - but it doesn't prevent the #Bytes in All Heaps from slowly growing.
However if I explicitly run:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

It will collect all the extra consumed memory. (e.g. if run after 12 hours, heaps footprint drops by 20MB).
I was also trying to inspect the dump (before running `GC.Collect`) by sos and sosex - and majority of object hanging around are unrooted.

Why are not the implicit garbage collection runs (showed by performance counters) collecting the memory, that explicit `GC.Collect()` call does?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that objects that are remaining to hang around unrooted are NOT implementing IDisposable - so they should be reclaimed during the first run of GC on that particular generation (in another words - potential problem with wrong Dispose() method and deadlocked finalizer is out of question here. But points up to Stephen and Roy for pointing to this possibility)

Comment: What are you doing in your application? Could be you are not disposing your objects correctly, and in the long run causing memory leaks.

Comment: I was under the impression the implicit garbage collection might only do it if memory concerns are an issue.  If the box you're on isn't running out of resources, it might keep that memory around for future allocations.

Comment: Why does it matter? The purpose of GC is not to reduce memory footprint. It is to ensure the application doesn't run out of memory. As long as you have enough memory, why would the automatic collections do any more work than they have to? That would just slow down your application, which *most* people consider to be a bad thing.

Comment: All implicit does is call GC.Collect when it thinks it's needed as opposed to when you think it is. Given you haven't mentioned a case where explicitly managing memory is required, poor control of lifetimes is indicated, as does the fact the memory usage is constantly growing.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson So does it mean that even if '#Gen 2 Collections' performance counter is growing, the collection itself might not be actually happening?
I was under impression that the runtime wouldn't call the particular generation collection AT ALL if it wouldn't consider it necessary (memory pressure in the process or on the machine)

Comment: @jalf You are correct. My main concern isn't actually about the footprint, but about the potential of problems in longer run.
My performance counters are showing that garbage collection is occurring, but that it actually doesn't collect the unrooted objects

Comment: None of this makes any sense, GC.Collect() doesn't run a different collection than normal collects do.  Getting lost in sos and drawing the wrong conclusions is very likely, it isn't a very friendly tool and the odds that you use it at the right time, right after a gen#2 collection, are very low.  Do consider investing in a better managed memory profiler.

Comment: @user230810. Too difficult to say what it going on from here. But the question I'd be asking myself is why have I got all this stuff in generation 2? First thing I'd look would be explicit calls to GC.Collect...

Answer (score 3):

The garbage collector is actually pretty intelligent. It does not collect memory if it doesn't have to, and that provides it some optimization flexibility.

It keeps open the option of **resurrecting** the objects that require finalization but that are not yet finalized. As long as the memory is not required, the garbage collector thus does not force the finalization, just in case it can resurrect those objects.

Comment: `The garbage collector is actually pretty intelligent` I wouldn't say that, considering that in some cases, calling `GC.Collect()` actually **avoids** getting the dreaded `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @Nolonar, I'm saying it's pretty intelligent, not that it has psychic powers ;-)

Comment: @RoyDictus You are correct that just the occurrence of garbage collection doesn't guarantee that the memory used by unrooted objects would be reclaimed - in case the object is Disposable - as it first need to be put in finalizer queue, finalized and then the subsequent GC would reclaim the memory.
However my object that stay hanging in memory are not implementing IDisposable (so problem with deadlocking the finalizer is out of question). I'll edit my question to mention this explicitly.

Comment: @OP, this isn't about `IDisposable`, it's about having a finalizer. Still whether you have finalizers or not, the GC will collect when it deems necessary to do so. So calling `GC.Collect()` explicitly means you're making it consider at that time whether it's a good idea to collect. It's not a command to collect **immediately**. In other words: if the garbage collector doesn't collect, it means it doesn't need to.